# How to add labels to Prometheus Summary metric in Java

Tags: java, summary, prometheus

Counters and Gauges allow for labels to be added to them.  When I try to add labels to a Summary, I get an "incorrect number of labels" error.

This is what I'm trying:

```
private static final Summary latencySummary = Summary.build()
            .name("all_latencies")
            .help("all latencies.")
            .register();

latencySummary.labels("xyz_api_latency").observe(timer.elapsedSeconds());
```

I've looked at the Summary github source code, but can't find the answer. How are labels added to a Summary?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to [provide the labelname in the metric](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java#labels):

```
private static final Summary latencySummary = Summary.build()
    .name("latency_seconds")
    .help("All latencies.")
    .labelNames("api")
    .register();
```

Comment: how can I add more than one label? @brian-brazil

Comment: Try .labelNames("label1","label2")

Comment: I did as suggested. When I check the data I get a trailing comma in my metric. Like this: sample_counter{method="POST",status="520",} 1.0       Not sure where I am getting that additional comma from.

Answer (score 5):

So following is an other example where we can see how to define the labels and the set the actual values:

```java
Gauge mem_usage = Gauge.build().name("mem_usage").help("Memory usage").labelNames("label1", "label2").register();
mem_usage.labels("label1_value1", "label2_value2").set(1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Histogram and labels working example:-**

```
import io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry;
import io.prometheus.client.Histogram;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class HistogramService {

    private final Histogram requestDuration;

    private HistogramService(CollectorRegistry collectorRegistry){
        requestDuration = Histogram.build()
                .name("http_request_latency")
                .help("http request latency.")
                .labelNames("label1", "label2")
                .buckets(.005, .01, .025, .05, .075, .1, .25, .5, .75, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10)
                .register(collectorRegistry);
    }

    public void histogramMetrics() {

        Histogram.Timer requestTimer = requestDuration.labels("label1Value", "label2Value").startTimer();
        try {
           long sleepDuration  = Double.valueOf(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 * 1000)).longValue();
            Thread.sleep(sleepDuration);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        requestTimer.observeDuration();
    }
}
```